# Dask - "'coroutine' object is not iterable" trying to read parquet from S3

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

Using this code to read a multi-part parquet files with the prefix '/data/key' from a private s3 bucket, not from AWS

```py
import dask as dd
dd.read_parquet(
    's3://ns1/data/key',
    storage_options={
        'key': 'key',
        'secret': 'secret',
        'client_kwargs': {'endpoint_url': 'https://s3.sample-private-cloud.com'}
    }
)
```

Why am I getting an error:

```py
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable
```

I was able to download the file using boto3 client but unable to read it using dask. Dask documentation doesn't mention asynchronous process anywhere (await, async), so not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using this code to read a multi-part parquet files with the prefix '/data/key'

If you are trying to load all files with a prefix 'data/key', you should add a * at the end of the pattern, like this `'data/key*'`:

```py
import dask as dd
dd.read_parquet(
    's3://ns1/data/key*',
    storage_options={
        'key': 'key',
        'secret': 'secret',
        'client_kwargs': {'endpoint_url': 'https://s3.sample-private-cloud.com'}
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure how I missed that. :-) –